# Very basic "sleep calculator" algorithm in C using cs50 library

Tags: beginner, algorithm, c

I've been following along with CS50 online and tried my first shot at making a program from scratch and without guidelines. I hope you may be able to rip it to shreds for me.

```
//
// this program determines how many hours you slept last night. 
// it assumes that: 
// you're using a 12 hour clock
// you sleep for a maximum of 24 hours
//

#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{   // get user bedtime
    printf("When did you go to bed last night?\n");
    int bedtime = GetInt();
    // determine AM or PM
    printf("AM [1]\nor\nPM [2]\n");
    int b = GetInt();
    // get user wake up time
    printf("When did you wake up this morning?\n");
    int wakeup = GetInt();
    // determine AM or PM
    printf("AM [1]\nor\nPM [2]\n");
    int w = GetInt();
    // interpret inputs and determine how to calculate hours slept
    {if ((b == 1) && (w == 1))
    {
        int slept = wakeup-bedtime;
        printf("You slept for %i hours last night\n",slept);

    }
    else if (((b == 1) && (w == 2)) || ((b == 2) && (w == 1)))
    {
        int slept = 12-bedtime+wakeup;
        printf("You slept for %i hours last night\n",slept);

    }
    else
    {
        int slept = (12-bedtime)+12+wakeup;
        printf("You slept for %i hours last night\n",slept);
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A few things:

- Naming: `b` and `w` aren't particularly descriptive.  Even `bampm` and `wampm` are better.
- You've got extra `{}` around your `if` statement for some reason.
- Your algorithm does a lot of tests.  What if you convert to 24-hour time?

  Doing so will let you get rid of `b` and `w` by changing `bedtime` and `wakeup` after you read them.

  ```
  printf("When did you go to bed last night?\n");
  int bedtime = GetInt();
  // determine AM or PM
  printf("AM [1]\nor\nPM [2]\n");
  int ampm = GetInt();
  // convert to 24-hour time
  if (ampm == 2) bedtime = bedtime + 12;
  // get user wake up time
  printf("When did you wake up this morning?\n");
  int wakeup = GetInt();
  // determine AM or PM
  printf("AM [1]\nor\nPM [2]\n");
  ampm = GetInt();
  // convert to 24-hour time
  if (ampm == 2) wakeup = wakeup + 12;
  ```

  Also, the conditionals get easier:

  ```
  int slept = wakeup - bedtime;
  if (slept < 0) { slept = slept + 24 } // math is your friend
  printf("You slept for %i hours last night\n",slept);
  ```
- Once principle of programming is "Don't Repeat Yourself" aka "DRY".  Do you really need 3 copies of the output printf?

  Of course not.  You can move it after the end of the `if` statement.
- Finally, I don't know if this was covered in class, but you're not doing any input checking.  What if the user puts in `3` instead of `1` or `2` ?  What if they put in times like `-5` or `27` ?